# XSL file to create grouped table for 3 columns

Tags: java, xslt

I am having the following issue: I am creating this xml file through java reflecting a class. An example of the xml file can be seen below:

```
<ShoppingLists>
  <ShoppigList>
      <SLNAME>List #1</SLNAME>
      <Store>
        <SNAME>Store 1</SNAME>
        <VEGETABLES>Carrots,Lettuce,Onions</VEGETABLES>
        <FRUITS>Grapes,Oranges</FRUITS>
        <MEATS>Beef</MEATS>
        <DRINKS></DRINKS>
      </Store>
      <Store>
        <name>Store 3</name>
        <VEGETABLES></VEGETABLES>
        <FRUITS></FRUITS>
        <MEATS></MEATS>
        <DRINKS>Beer</DRINKS>
      </Store>
  </ShoppigList>
  <ShoppigList>
      <SLNAME>List #2</SLNAME>
      <Store>
        <SNAME>Store 5</SNAME>
        <VEGETABLES></VEGETABLES>
        <FRUITS></FRUITS>
        <MEATS>Fish</MEATS>
        <DRINKS></DRINKS>
      </Store>
      <Store>
        <SNAME>Store 12</SNAME>
        <VEGETABLES>Cucumbers</VEGETABLES>
        <FRUITS>Peaches</FRUITS>
        <MEATS></MEATS>
        <DRINKS>Water</DRINKS>
      </Store>
  </ShoppigList>
<ShoppingList>
```

My xsl file that I have developed looks like the following:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

        <xsl:variable name="empty_string"/>

        <xsl:template match="/">
            <html>
                <body>
                    <h2>Master Shopping List</h2>
                    <table border="1">
                        <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                            <th>Shopping List</th>
                            <th>Store</th>
                            <th>Items</th>
                        </tr>
                        <xsl:for-each select="ShoppingLists/ShoppingList">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:apply-templates select="SLNAME"/>
                                </td>
                                <xsl:for-each select="/Store">
                                    <td>
                                        <xsl:apply-templates select="STORENAME"/>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <xsl:apply-templates select="VEGETABLES"/>  
                                        <xsl:apply-templates select="FRUITS"/>
                                        <xsl:apply-templates select="MEATS"/>
                                        <xsl:apply-templates select="DRINKS"/>
                                    </td>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </tr>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </table>
                </body>
            </html>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="SLNAME">
            <span style="color:#000000">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/></span>
            <br />
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="STORENAME">
            <span style="color:#000000">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/></span>
            <br />
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="VEGETABLES">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="* or normalize-space()">
                    Vegetables: <span style="color:#000000">
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </span>
                    <br />
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="FRUITS">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="* or normalize-space()">
                    Frtuis: <span style="color:#000000">
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </span>
                    <br />
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="MEATS">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="* or normalize-space()">
                    Meast: <span style="color:#000000">
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </span>
                    <br />
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="DRINKS">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="* or normalize-space()">
                    Drinks: <span style="color:#000000">
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </span>
                    <br />
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am having issues creating a table where it should look like the following:

```
Shopping List |  Store     | Items
------------------------------------
Shopping List | Store Name | Items | 
Name          |            |       |
              |--------------------|
              | Store Name | Items |
              |            |       |
------------------------------------
```

Can anyone help me out? Thanks.

Comment: Could you post the exact result expected from your example input? As code, please.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing(!) you want to do something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Shopping List</th>
            <th>Store</th>
            <th>Items</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ShoppingLists/ShoppingList" />         
    </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ShoppingList">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="{count(Store)}">
            <xsl:value-of select="SLNAME"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="Store[1]/SNAME"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Store[1]/*[string()]" /> 
        </td>           
    </tr>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Store[position() > 1]" />                      
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Store">
    <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="SNAME"/></td>
        <td>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*[string()]" /> 
        </td>                  
    </tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Store/*">
    <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
    <xsl:text>: </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <br/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="SNAME" priority="1"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to a corrected(!) **input** example:

```
<ShoppingLists>
  <ShoppingList>
      <SLNAME>List #1</SLNAME>
      <Store>
        <SNAME>Store 1</SNAME>
        <VEGETABLES>Carrots,Lettuce,Onions</VEGETABLES>
        <FRUITS>Grapes,Oranges</FRUITS>
        <MEATS>Beef</MEATS>
        <DRINKS></DRINKS>
      </Store>
      <Store>
        <SNAME>Store 3</SNAME>
        <VEGETABLES></VEGETABLES>
        <FRUITS></FRUITS>
        <MEATS></MEATS>
        <DRINKS>Beer</DRINKS>
      </Store>
  </ShoppingList>
  <ShoppingList>
      <SLNAME>List #2</SLNAME>
      <Store>
        <SNAME>Store 5</SNAME>
        <VEGETABLES></VEGETABLES>
        <FRUITS></FRUITS>
        <MEATS>Fish</MEATS>
        <DRINKS></DRINKS>
      </Store>
      <Store>
        <SNAME>Store 12</SNAME>
        <VEGETABLES>Cucumbers</VEGETABLES>
        <FRUITS>Peaches</FRUITS>
        <MEATS></MEATS>
        <DRINKS>Water</DRINKS>
      </Store>
  </ShoppingList>
</ShoppingLists>
```

the **result** will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<table border="1">
   <tr>
      <th>Shopping List</th>
      <th>Store</th>
      <th>Items</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">List #1</td>
      <td>Store 1</td>
      <td>VEGETABLES: Carrots,Lettuce,Onions<br/>FRUITS: Grapes,Oranges<br/>MEATS: Beef<br/>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Store 3</td>
      <td>DRINKS: Beer<br/>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">List #2</td>
      <td>Store 5</td>
      <td>MEATS: Fish<br/>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Store 12</td>
      <td>VEGETABLES: Cucumbers<br/>FRUITS: Peaches<br/>DRINKS: Water<br/>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

rendered as:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are three mistakes/typos in your input XML - each `<ShoppigList>` should be `<ShoppingList>`, the `<name>Store 3</name>` should be `<SNAME>Store 3</SNAME>` and the closing tag has to be `</ShoppingLists>` instead of `<ShoppingLists>`. If this is changed, following adjusted XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:variable name="empty_string"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <body>
            <h2>Master Shopping List</h2>
            <table border="1">
                <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                    <th>Shopping List</th>
                    <th>Store</th>
                    <th>Items</th>
                </tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="ShoppingLists/ShoppingList">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="SLNAME"/>
                        </td>
                        <xsl:for-each select="Store">
                            <td>
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="SNAME"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="VEGETABLES"/>
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="FRUITS"/>
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="MEATS"/>
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="DRINKS"/>
                            </td>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="SLNAME">
    <span style="color:#000000">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </span>
    <br />
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="SNAME">
    <span style="color:#000000">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </span>
    <br />
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="VEGETABLES">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="* or normalize-space()">
            Vegetables: <span style="color:#000000">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </span>
            <br />
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="FRUITS">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="* or normalize-space()">
            Frtuis: <span style="color:#000000">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </span>
            <br />
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="MEATS">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="* or normalize-space()">
            Meast: <span style="color:#000000">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </span>
            <br />
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="DRINKS">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="* or normalize-space()">
            Drinks: <span style="color:#000000">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </span>
            <br />
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to the adjusted input XML produces the output

```
<html>
 <body>
  <h2>Master Shopping List</h2>
  <table border="1">
     <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>Shopping List</th>
        <th>Store</th>
        <th>Items</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td><span style="color:#000000">List #1</span><br></td>
        <td><span style="color:#000000">Store 1</span><br></td>
        <td>
           Vegetables: <span style="color:#000000">Carrots,Lettuce,Onions</span><br>
           Frtuis: <span style="color:#000000">Grapes,Oranges</span><br>
           Meast: <span style="color:#000000">Beef</span><br></td>
        <td><span style="color:#000000">Store 3</span><br></td>
        <td>
           Drinks: <span style="color:#000000">Beer</span><br></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td><span style="color:#000000">List #2</span><br></td>
        <td><span style="color:#000000">Store 5</span><br></td>
        <td>
           Meast: <span style="color:#000000">Fish</span><br></td>
        <td><span style="color:#000000">Store 12</span><br></td>
        <td>
           Vegetables: <span style="color:#000000">Cucumbers</span><br>
           Frtuis: <span style="color:#000000">Peaches</span><br>
           Drinks: <span style="color:#000000">Water</span><br></td>
     </tr>
   </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Following adjustments:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Store">
   <td>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="SNAME"/>
   </td>
```

instead of

```
<xsl:for-each select="/Store">
    <td>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="STORENAME"/>
    </td>
```

and adjusted the match pattern

```
<xsl:template match="STORENAME">
```

to

```
<xsl:template match="SNAME">
```

**Update:** I've already noticed that this is not the full solution - the shops for each shopping list have to be each on a single row, and the shopping list has to have a corresponding rowspan -  and will update the answer in some minutes in case there won't be already a full solution given.

**Update:** As the correct answer was just given by michael.hor257k, there's no need for further adjustments, but for the additional information provided about some adjustments to the input XML and the XSLT I´ll keep this half-answer for the moment.